# How to reduce requestLayout() lag in animations?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, optimization, drawing

I'm trying to animate the width of a `TextView`, on my Redmi Note 4 it worked flawlessly. However when tested on a slightly slower phone (1.2 GHz quad core) the animation was uglily lagging.

After some starter debugging, turned out that calling `requestLayout()` was the culprit, it dropped many frames, and upon further inspection, turned out `onMeasure()`, *which is the first method called when redrawing*, is being called A LOT for only 1 `TextView` being animated. It's probable that the rest of the parent hierarchy calls it bubblin' to the root.

This is absolutely no bueno in my case. I'm attempting to animate both width and height. I use `ValueAnimator` and call `requestLayout` inside `onAnimationUpdate()`, I tried calling `requestLayout()` inside one of them only, but it nearly had no impact at all.

```
final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = container.getLayoutParams();

ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(this.width, ((int) (this.screenWidth / 1.5)));
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        layoutParams.width = (int) (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
    }
});
anim.setDuration(duration);
anim.start();

anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(this.height, this.screenHeight / 2);
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        layoutParams.height = (int) (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
        container.requestLayout();
    }
});
anim.setDuration(duration);
anim.start();
```

I tried making a custom `StaticLayout` to exploit some of this approach's efficiency and performance optimizations but it didn't help either. After all the `View` class itself is what's calling `onMeasure()` repeatedly, so how can I prevent that and only update the `TextView` I'm willing to resize? Of course `invalidate()` wouldn't work because it'll miss the resizing job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I discovered that using `beginDelayedTransition()` with a `ConstraintSet` on a `ConstraintLayout` proves to be more efficient and smoother than manual animations.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the device's graphics rendering capabilities.
So you are getting the differences in devices.
If there are frame drops, you should not amaze out of it.

one reason might be:
 - You are animating from a certain width to screenWidth/1.5, which is much large I think.

Let's say you are animating from 48 to 480

initialValue: 48

finalValue : 480

duration: 200ms

It means (480-48) = 432 steps/re-draw in 200 ms
then, approx 2 draw per millisecond.

So you are giving less than a millisecond for 1 drawing.
Ideally, if time draw time goes above 16ms then there are frame drops.
In your case, you are trying too much re-drawings due to requestLayout call.

An ideal condition for drawing 432 frames is like:

`1 frame -> 20 ms (some extra time given)
432 frames -> 8640 ms`

Try to reduce the number of calls to requestLayout to prevent `onMeasure()` calls.

Comment: I tried skipping odd/even iterations in the animation, but this resulted in a VERY stuttered animation.